# How can we customize API Management developer portal using GitHub code

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to modify APIM portal using https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/releases . But the changes are not reflecting. Is there a way to reflect the changes?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the managed portal through the self hosted one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.